# What are some good persistance libraries for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, ibatis

I come from a Java background and am getting more into .NET, what are some good libraries to use in my DAO layers?  I'm used to using MyBatis (this appears to exist but not in a real full release).  I've used Hibernate, which apparently exists in .NET but I'd rather avoid a full POJO style object mapper.  I'd really like a library that is query based like MyBatis.  Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which ORM for .NET would you recommend?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132676/which-orm-for-net-would-you-recommend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the latest entity framework by microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx.  They've made great progress with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the one that StackOverflow is using. [Dapper.NET](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Comment: After a quick look it looks really nice, I wonder if you can externalize the SQL so it's not in your class files.

Comment: Queries and commands are defined by strings, you can externalize them.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate in .Net can be very nice with Linq to NHibernate. While the setup can be tedious, I still think I like NHibernate more than Hibernate. (Be it because of C# vs Java is a debate)

Comment: Add FluentNhibernate with Auto Convention mappings and the tediousness of the setup goes away

Comment: I never linked FNH. NHibernate config is just XML. I really meant getting into NHibernate initially was tedious - what files to mark as embedded, etc. There's a steep learning curve.